# How to view Growl logs?

Tags: macos, growl

I'd like to view the logs that Growl generates, but don't know where to look for that.
Running Mac OS X Leopard, Growl 1.2.1

The notifications my code posts using gntp-send library work sometimes, but don't work other times, so I would like to see Growl logs to understand what is the difference.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can add that functionality [with Geek Tool](http://gthing.net/enable-growl-log-and-show-it-in-geektool).

Comment: Thanks! The commands to enable log collection worked. Plain text reading of the log file suffices for me, so I didn't go further to install GeekTool. Nevertheless the log helped to solve the problem. Thanks again